# how to handle non ascii characters in where clause

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, mysql-python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing the problem with non-ascii character in where clause using with Oracle, MySQL, snowflake query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE col = 'Niño Pobre, Niño Rico';
```

This query returns no result.

Is there any solution to handle non-ascii character in where clause then please reply me.

Thanks.

Comment: `select * from table where col = N'Niño Pobre, Niño Rico';`

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? They belong to the same company but they're different products. Also, you need to decide what "handle" means. Should `Niño` match `Nino`? Should it *not* match? Last but not least, what encodings are your applicaton and database using?

Comment: @lad2025, It is not working in Oracle or Mysql, It is working in SQL.

Comment: @Álvaro González, I am using both Oracle and Mysql database.Yes,it should match Niño with Nino but i have no any idea how to match it.If you have any idea then let me know.

Comment: I don't think there's a cross-DBMS solution for that. In MySQL you need to find a collation that implements the rules you want (and you probably need to avoid Spanish collations) and set it with e.g. the [COLLATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html) clause. In Oracle you need to play with [session parameters and function arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm). As you can see, the syntax couldn't differ more

Comment: Snowflake supports queries like that. I suspect the problem is you using Python. Python doesn't like non-ascii characters by default. Have you tested from a command line? If the Python is the problem, let us know, I can post an example Python program where it all works (for Snowflake)

Comment: yes, I have run the query from snowflake editor but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maurcin and user3278684 made comments about the Snowflake Data wharehouse.

In Snowflake when working with data with multiple languages, the COLLATION() function is very helpful.

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/collate.html
- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/collation.html
- Considerations and limitations, supported functions used to search are listed: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/collation.html#limited-support-for-collation-in-built-in-functions

So say for instance you have a table called feedback with two columns

---

|    id          | feedback_string       |

---

|     1            | 'Niño Pobre, Niño Rico'|

---

> SELECT collate(feedback_string) from feedback
> WHERE feedback_string like '%Niño Pobre, Niño Rico%';

If you wanted to create a table to search for strings that are a specific language, you can create the same table above in Snowflake like this:

> CREATE TABLE feedback (id NUMBER, feedback_string varchar(20) collate 'sp');
>
> INSERT INTO collation1 (v) VALUES (1, 'Niño Pobre, Niño Rico');

then you can search with Like, but know that the search for for N will be close to ñ.